# CubeJS - calculated measure based on total measure value for the response

Tags: javascript, node.js, cube, cube.js

I want to create a calculated measure `amountPercentage` in CubeJS. I have an `amount` measure and I want to check how many percentages from the whole amount (sum for all records in response) is in every single record.

Let's say I have `Products` dimension: Shoes, Jackets. Shoes `amount = 30`, Jackets `amount = 120`.
The measure `amountPercentage` should be 20% for shoes.

Any way to achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

Best practice for such kind of queries is to handle this on the client side and split it into separate queries. Typical queries for such use case are:

1. Fetch absolute amounts for top 10:

```js
{
  dimensions: ['Products.name'],
  measures: ['Sales.amount'],
  timeDimensions: [{
    dimension: 'Sales.time',
    dateRange: 'Last 30 days'
  }],
  limit: 10
}
```

2. Fetch total amount:

```js
{
  measures: ['Sales.amount'],
  timeDimensions: [{
    dimension: 'Sales.time',
    dateRange: 'Last 30 days'
  }]
}
```

3. Fetch other than top 10 products total amount:

```js
{
  measures: ['Sales.amount'],
  filters: [{
    member: 'Products.name',
    operator: 'notEquals',
    values: [...top10ProductNames]
  }],
  timeDimensions: [{
    dimension: 'Sales.time',
    dateRange: 'Last 30 days'
  }]
}
```

Then percentages are calculated on the client side.

Comment: Is this still correct advice? Doing such calculation client side defeats the purpose of using a headless BI & metrics store.

Comment: @dendog A bit late to the game, but [dynamic measures seem to be the way to go](https://cube.dev/docs/recipes/referencing-dynamic-measures). You would have to programmatically compute the `Products` dimension (or hardcode it)

Comment: @dendog Still correct advice for Headless BI approach. Cube SQL API uses multiple queries and post-processing for complex SQL queries like these.

Comment: @PavelTiunov I think using plain SQL is a better development experience in that case - less error prone.